# mmreader not working in 2007a, 64BIT Win7

Tags: matlab

mmreader is not working for me in my 2007a version, I am using a WIN& 64bit
The code I wrote is :

vidread=mmreader(video_file_name);

Comment: What happened? Were there any sort of error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to know what **specific** error you get, but the most likely reason is that `mmreader` is a function only available in newer versions of MATLAB.

Try using `aviread` instead:

```
vidread = aviread(video_file_name)
```